# Cannot read property of map of undefined when using featureSelector ngrx

Tags: angular, ngrx

REPO: https://github.com/morningharwood/platform/tree/feature/ngrx-firebase

When I try to subscribe to my selectAll of my post ngrx entity feature I get the error:

> Cannot read property of map of undefined

It has to be a simple typo I'm following tutorials verbatim.

Weird part is if I use string selector:

```
 this.selected$ = this.store.select('post');

 this.selected$.subscribe(console.log); // no error here.
```

I get a no error.

Question:
When using ngrx entity, How can I get my `selectAll` selector to log out the  all posts from ngrx store collection `post`?

My `post.reducer.ts`

```
import {
  PostActions,
  PostActionTypes,
} from './post.actions';

import {
  ActionReducerMap,
  createFeatureSelector,
} from '@ngrx/store';
import {
  createEntityAdapter,
  EntityState,
} from '@ngrx/entity';
import { Post } from './post.interfaces';

export const postAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Post>();
export interface PostState extends EntityState<Post> {}

export const postInitialState: PostState = {
  ids: [ '1234' ],
  entities: {
    '1234': {
      id: '1234',
      header: {
        title: 'title 1',
        subtitle: 'subtitle 1',
      },
      body: {
        sections: [],
      },
    },
  },
};

export const initialState: PostState = postAdapter.getInitialState(postInitialState);

export function postReducer(state: PostState = initialState, action: PostActions): PostState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PostActionTypes.ADD_ONE:
      return postAdapter.addOne(action.post, state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const getPostState = createFeatureSelector<PostState>('post');
export const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll: selectAllPosts,
  selectTotal,
} = postAdapter.getSelectors(getPostState);

export const postReducersMap: ActionReducerMap<any> = {
  post: postReducer,
};
```

And `app.component`:

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { AppState } from './app.interfaces';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { selectAllPosts } from './post/post.reducer';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public selected$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.selected$ = this.store.select(selectAllPosts);
    this.selected$.subscribe(console.log); // error here
  }
}
```

My `forFeature`and `forRoot` modules:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'portfolio-app' }),
    StoreModule.forRoot({ reducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
    PostModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
}

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { postReducers } from './post.reducer';


@NgModule({
  exports: [],
  declarations: [],
  imports: [StoreModule.forFeature('post', postReducersMap)],
})
export class PostModule {
}
```

Comment: What do you get by doing `this.store.select('post').subscribe((p) => console.log(p))`?

Comment: An error about map undefined

Comment: It seems like you haven't defined any selector for `selectAllPosts`. You should set up a selector that takes the global states and returns only the posts.

Comment: @AndreaM16 I thought createFeatureSelector() and getSelectors() deconstructed would give me the selected.  I guess the question is what does selectAll do from ngrx/entity if not a selector itself

Comment: UPDATE it was the creation of the ActionMapReducer in the forFeature('post', postReducerMap);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the creation of the `ActionMapReducer` in the `forFeature('post', postReducerMap);`  I still need to figure out how to use entity and ActionMapReducer together.

Comment: It just might so happen to be that you forgot
export const getPizzaState = createFeatureSelector<State>('user');
export const { selectAll } = adapter.getSelectors(getPizzaState);

Comment: Do you have solution on this?

Comment: @miszczak I've given 2 solutions.  The checked answer being that I was composing the ActionMapReducers improperly or you forgot to make the createFeatureSelector

Answer (score 15):

For people who come across this in the future this can be solved by refactoring the selectors slightly.

As per the (somewhat incomplete at the time of posting) docs here, [ngrx.io/entity/adapter](https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter), you need to select the featureSate using the `createFeatureSelector` function and then use that substate with the adapter selectors to select slices of that state.

Change this:

`post.reducer.ts`

```
export const getPostState = createFeatureSelector<PostState>('post');
export const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll: selectAllPosts,
  selectTotal,
} = postAdapter.getSelectors(getPostState);
```

to this:

```
export const selectPostState = createFeatureSelector<PostState>('post');
export const {
  selectIds,
  selectEntities,
  selectAll
  selectTotal,
} = postAdapter.getSelectors();

export const selectPostIds = createSelector(
  selectPostState,
  selectIds
 );

export const selectPostEntities = createSelector(
  selectPostState,
  selectEntities
);

export const selectAllPosts = createSelector(
  selectPostState,
  selectAll
);
```

This will select the substate of the `postState` feature.

Hope this helps

Edit: So it appears the above two examples are equivalent and the issues I was facing was the same as [Matthew Harwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191635/matthew-harwood) and it was improper use of the `ActionReducerMap`.

I think the docs might be a bit confusing on this as they lead to believe that the state of and entity is the same thing as the state of a feature state such as a lazy loaded state.

While an entity state has properties such as id's and entities, they do not need a reduce each like feature state does but only one reducer to cover all the entity state for that model.

e.g.

```
export const initialState: PostState = postAdapter.getInitialState(postInitialState);
```

does not need a reducer map for the `PostAdapterState` because the one reducer

```
export function postReducer(state: PostState = initialState, action: 
PostActions): PostState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PostActionTypes.ADD_ONE:
      return postAdapter.addOne(action.post, state);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Covers all the entity state updating.

You would need a reducer map if you multiple adapter states in a feature state such as the example below.

Lets say you had a Library feature state that and entities of books and magazines. It would look something like the below.

`book.reducer.ts`

```
export interface BookEntityState extends EntityState<Book> {
  selectedBookId: string | null;
}

const bookAdapter: EntityAdapter<Book> = createEntityAdapter<Book>();

export const initialBookState: BookEntityState = adapter.getInitialState({
  selectedBookId: null
});

export const bookReducer (...) ... etc
```

`magazine.reducer.ts`

```
export interface MagazineEntityState extends EntityState<Magazine> {
  selectedMagazineId: string | null;
}

const magazineAdapter: EntityAdapter<Magazine> = createEntityAdapter<Magazine>();

export const initialMagazineState: MagazineEntityState = 
adapter.getInitialState({
  selectedMagazineId: null
});

export const magazineReducer (...) ... etc
```

And then you library feature state may be something like

`library.reducer.ts`

```
// Feature state,
export interface LibraryFeatureState {
  books: BookEntityState
  magazines: MagazineEntityState
}

// Reducer map of the lirbray
export const libraryReducersMap: ActionReducerMap<LibraryFeatureState> = {
  books: bookReducer,
  magazines: magazineReducer
};
```

And then adding the feature state to your Store in the LibraryModule imports array.

`library.module.ts`

```
...
StoreModule.forFeature<LibraryFeatureState>('libraryState', 
libraryReducersMap),
...
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: While following the docs you mentioned I notice that something wasn't right. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem trying to create a selector with the following

```
export const selectFuturMenus = createSelector(
  selectMenuState,
  fromMenu.selectAll,
  (state, menus: Menu[], props) => menus.filter(menu => {
    let startMmt = moment(menu.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    let endMmt = moment(menu.end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    let mmt = moment();
    console.log(startMmt, endMmt);
    return mmt.isBefore(endMmt);
  })
);
```

It seems we can't use an adapter selector before a filter function.
Following the NgRX documentation a simple solution is to decompose the selector like this

```
export const selectAllMenus = createSelector(
  selectMenuState,
  fromMenu.selectAll,
);

export const selectFuturMenus = createSelector(
  selectAllMenus,
  (menus: Menu[], props) => menus.filter(menu => {
    let startMmt = moment(menu.start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    let endMmt = moment(menu.end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    let mmt = moment();
    return mmt.isBefore(endMmt);
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling my mind around same issue during a couple of hours and I finally realized that the source of my issue was related with the reduced function, concretely my reducer function was not returning the default state  at the end of the switch statement.

As I said it took me a while to find it out and I hope my answer to help anybody else to fix this issue sooner than me.

```
switch (action.type) {

    case ActionType:
      return adapter.addAll(action.payload, state);

    default:
      return state;
  }
```